# Alexa test ISP with lambda-local

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to create my first Alexa skill with In Skill Purchasing (ISP), and having issues testing consistently locally.

When I copy my JSON Input from the "Alexa Console > Test" area and run the same request using lambda-local in vscode, it often works a few times but inevitably I end up getting the following response:

`ServiceError: The authentication token is invalid or doesn&#39;t have access to make this request`

`at MonetizationServiceClient.<anonymous> (<my_path>/lambda/custom/node_modules/ask-sdk-model/index.js:149:35)`

Sometimes I get the response the first try, sometimes after 2 or 3 attempts.

I'm testing with an amazon.com account using a US based address as recommended, and I'm using en-US locale, so why do I keep getting this error message that my authentication token is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind to check if you added ".withApiClient(new Alexa.DefaultApiClient())" which is a mandatory to add whenever serviceClientFactory called in Alexa skill.

Check below link to know where to add "withApiClient(new Alexa.DefaultApiClient())":
https://github.com/alexa-samples/skill-sample-nodejs-consumable-hello-world/blob/master/lambda/custom/index.js#L801

I hope this helps you.